# Changing trackpad scroll direction with AppleScript in Yosemite

Tags: applescript, trackpad, macos

I prefer "natural" scroll direction when using my MBAir trackpad, but "unnatural" when using the mouse. I frequently switch back and forth depending on where I'm working, so I've been using a bit of AppleScript to switch the setting. This script stopped working when I upgraded to Mac OS Yosemite. It still opens the Scroll & Zoom pane of the Trackpad preferences, but it doesn't click the checkbox. I've tried a few things but I can't get it to work.. I'm not an Apple Developer, so I don't have any debugging tools. Any tips?

```
try
    tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
    end tell

    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
            click radio button "Scroll & Zoom" of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
            click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
        end tell
    end tell
end try
```

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure Applescripts has permission to modify apps. 
This can be done by opening `System Preferences | Security & Privacy | Accessibility` and checking *Script Editor*. This is a one time process and you shouldn't have to check it again.

[image]

I ran this same snippet @Bowen provided in his question on Mojave and noticed what he described. I fixed it by adding the delay mentioned by @Bowen in his answer. The box would either check or uncheck now that we have added a small delay.

**Here is that example I ran directly from Script Editor:**

```
try
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
end tell
delay 2
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click radio button "Scroll & Zoom" of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
        click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    end tell
end tell
end try
```

Also, In relation to this topic, I built something using ideas from this thread, since folks may want to automate it per their settings. The below script is "Automator ready", or can be exported as an application so you can run it at startup or however you want to execute it. You have to also allow access to the exported application as shown in the image above for "Scroll direction Clicker". This is specific to a Logitech mouse being found, but it can easily be modified to any other type of string/mouse type. It can also be used as a decent reference to build off of for scroll-direction. I for one got tired of flipping scroll-direction when going from mouse to trackpad, and that's how I found this thread.

**Tailored to be exported as an Application from within Script Editor**

```
try
    set logitech to "Logitech"
    try
        set scriptOutput to do shell script "system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep -i logitech"
        if scriptOutput contains logitech then
            tell application "System Preferences"
                activate
                set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
            end tell
            delay 2
            tell application "System Events"
                tell process "System Preferences"
                    set checkBoxOne to checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
                    click radio button "Scroll & Zoom" of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
                    tell checkBoxOne to if value is 1 then click
                    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
                end tell
            end tell
        end if
    on error errMsg
        log errMsg
        tell application "System Preferences"
            activate
            set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
        end tell
        delay 2
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "System Preferences"
                set checkBoxOne to checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
                click radio button "Scroll & Zoom" of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
                tell checkBoxOne to if value is 0 then click
                tell application "System Preferences" to quit
            end tell
        end tell
    end try
end try
```

Comment: I'm using your 1st example in an Automator service. When I trigger it from another app (say, Safari), the Security and Privacy area wants me to grant access for that app to control System Preferences and System Events. 
I don't necessarily want to do that, nor do I want to have to authorize each app that I may have open. 
Is there any way around this? Do I have something configured incorrectly? Or is this just part of the Mojave security changes?

Comment: I updated my answer to show that you should only have to grant access once. After that, you shouldn't have to continuously do that. Also, as far as I know, you cannot run a script/Automator without granting it access as this is a security concern and by approving it you're consenting to that risk–even if it's not a risky program.

Answer (score 3):

*Change "activate" to "run" to make the script run in the background. also add "quit" to the end of the script with a delay of 0.6 to quit system preferences after executing the script.*

```
try
tell application "System Preferences"
    (run)
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        delay 0.6
        click radio button "Scroll & Zoom" of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
        click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
    end tell

    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
end tell
end try
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I am making a small go wrapper program to execute this. Will be adding you as the contributor under the GitHub repo.

Comment: glad it helped.

Comment: https://github.com/kaushikb1996/mac-inverse-click/

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this without any applescript:
https://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question: If this script isn't working, go to System Preferences | Security & Privacy | Accessibility, and make sure that Script Editor is checked ON to allow Applescripts to control the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **slightly modified** version of [the answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/348905/353345) provided by @TODO, and it is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16719614) to a related question. This AppleScript will switch the scrolling directly silently/invisibly. I save it as an application and launch it via spotlight whenever I switch between the mouse and the trackpad.

```
try
    tell application "System Preferences"
        reveal pane "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
            click radio button "Scroll & Zoom" of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
            click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
        end tell
    end tell
end try
```

Edited: I forgot to mention that I need to grant the **permission** of accessibility for once (when prompted). After the one-time prompt, it works like charm

Answer (score 0):

So what was happening was it was cycling thought the code to fast. So what i did was put delays in between where it wasn't working and it works perfectly fine. If you want to you could reduce the delay down to 0.5 or 0.2

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        delay (1)
        click radio button "Scroll & Zoom" of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
        delay (1)
        click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window "Trackpad"
        delay (1)
    end tell
end tell

Answer (score 0):

I created a small **Mac MenuBar-App** to automate this behaviour ([Scrolly](https://github.com/lucaArchidiacono/Scrolly)). What is the difference - you may ask - to [scrollreverser](https://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/). The [scrollreverser](https://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/) app is really nice but the downside to it is, that it doesn't actually change the settings (which my app does, thanks to you guys and the apple scripts everyone shared inside this thread).

If you want you can take a look in [here](https://github.com/lucaArchidiacono/Scrolly) and give it a try. Min. requirements are MacOS 11. As I wanted to test SwiftUI 2, I had to bump the min. version.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "trackpadTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.trackpad"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window 0
end tell

quit application "System Preferences"
```

I borrowed the code from [here](https://github.com/liesislukas/apple-scroll-direction-auto-toggle/blob/main/toggle.applescript).

Comment: this no longer works, since the pane id "com.apple.preference.trackpad" is deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/systempreferences#properties

Answer (score 0):

For macOS Ventura:

```
try
 
 tell application "System Settings"
  activate
 end tell
 
 delay 1
 
 if application "System Settings" is running then
  
  tell application "System Events"
   tell application process "System Settings"
    click menu item "Trackpad" of menu "View" of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1
    delay 0.5
    click radio button 2 of tab group 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Trackpad"
    delay 0.3
    click checkbox "Natural scrolling" of group 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Trackpad"
    
    
    click menu item "Close" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
   end tell
  end tell
 end if
on error errMsg number errNum
 display alert "Error " & errNum & ": " & errMsg
end try
```

It is far from perfect but it does get the job done.
Maybe the delay needs to be more, but with 1 it worked for me every time while testing