# Natural Scroll Direction: On with trackpad, Off with mouse

Tags: mouse, trackpad, macos

I already tried this:
[Changing trackpad scroll direction with AppleScript in Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153243/changing-trackpad-scroll-direction-with-applescript-in-yosemite)

But it didn't work.

What I need is when I use the internal macBook Pro trackpad, natural scroll direction is enabled, and when I use an external mouse, it is disabled.

If this is impossible, how about the following alternative: when I plug in a mouse switch to "non-natural" scroll direction, and when I disconnect the mouse switch back to natural.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hi just found a great app that totally fixed this and so simple! You can set the scroll direction for each device separately.

SCROLL REVERSER
http://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/

Comment: Not working on catalina.

Comment: @PiotrWittchen When I use Scroll Reverser in Monterey to only reverse external mice it makes trackpad scrolling go both ways, arbitrarily. While scrolling down, at certain speeds it starts scrolling up...

Comment: I don't know how it can behave with different external mouses. I'm not using Apple mouse. I'm using Logitech MX mouse.

Answer (score 5):

I got frustrated about this too. I found scroll reverser but it didn't seem to work reliably and other report it doesn't work at all on Catalina. I decided to develop my own app to fix the issue called UnnaturalScrollWheels, it also allows to disable scroll acceleration and modify the number of lines each wheel click scrolls.

https://github.com/ther0n/UnnaturalScrollWheels

Comment: Thank you for your work. I had this problem for a week now your software fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Go to **Accessibility** settings for **Mouse & Trackpad** in **System Preferences**.

Tick the

> "Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present"

option.

[image: Accessibility]

Then, with your mouse connected, go back to your **Mouse** settings in the **System Preferences** and adjust scrolling accordingly.

[image: Mouse and Trackpad settings]

Comment: Glad it helped you some!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Sierra

Comment: The answer was for Yosemite as per OP question. Written long before Sierra existed.

Comment: Ignoring trackpad does not mean, setting different scroll directions for mouse and trackpad or this option does something different, than it says.